# Sidebar with offset doesn't work. What do I wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I use stickToTop (http://sdbondi.github.io/jquery-sticktotop/) from fixate.it to make an sidebar that will move when you scroll down.

Here is my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6VwP/

Everything there is going just fine..just how I want it, but when I use it in my code program it doesn't work at all.

I think it has something to do how I put the js code in the index.html but I am not sure. 
I put this script link in the body:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sdbondi.github.io/jquery-sticktotop/jquery-sticktotop.js"></script>
```

My other javascript I made in an apart document called: jquery.stickToTop.js this code is  in te head code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stickToTop.js"></script>
```

The code of the stickToTop.js is:

```
;(function () {


var navHeight = $('.sticky').outerHeight(true);

$('.js-sticky').stickToTop({ offset: {top: 50}});


})();
```

So, what do I wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you have them in the body and not in the head instead?

Comment: please tell us how you're implementing the code in your script.js file!

Comment: @AminJafari it's now in the question.

Comment: @RachelGallen somebody told me it works better but even If I do it in the head it doesn't work either.

Comment: it doesn't matter where you include the <script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is fine in fiddle because it presumes the jQuery.ready function I suppose you have to change your jQuery code to this:

```
$(function () {


var navHeight = $('.sticky').outerHeight(true);

$('.js-sticky').stickToTop({ offset: {top: 50}});


});
```

let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have another question you may know. Do you know how to give also a width for this javascript? Is that something like: offset: {width:50}}); ?

Comment: no, offset only has top, right, bottom and left. if you want to give width to the '.js-sticky' you need to achieve it like this: `$('.js-sticky').width(200)` note that you don't need to set px at the end!